# SeekBar pointer not in the centre Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I am making a SeekBar in my Android Java application for the first time, but the slider circle is not in the middle of the line as I would expect, but a little above it. I can't figure out why this is the case.

There is an image of the slider at https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAGkM.jpg

My layout for the slider is:

```
    <SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="#ffff4007"
    android:progress="0"
    android:max="100"/>
```

Comment: Give it a maxHeight attr like android:maxHeight="300sp" - It fixes the position/gravity issues.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can post the code of your layout to better help you, maybe you can try this

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score -1):

To do this use
android: progress=0
In java use 
Seekbar.setmax(to set maxm value..as integer);